# Discs in R2 homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology

I am studying for comprehensive exams and am struggling on this next question more than I should be:

Let $X$ be the closed disc $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x^2+y^2\leq1\}$ minus the point $(1,0)$ and let $Y$ be the open disc $\{(x,y):x^2+y^2<1\}$ union the point $(1,0)$. Is $X$ homeomorphic to $Y$?

Well, they are both simply connected. Also, $Y$ is a deformation retract of $X$, but I don't think that means they are homeomorphic (just that fundamental groups are isomorphic). Removing points from interiors preserves all the topological properties I know of. But I am struggling with providing a proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you remove two distinct points from the boundary of $X$ the result still retract to a point. But if you remove two distinct points from Y, the result does not have a trivial fundamental group, so they are not homeomorphic.

Comment: ..would u like to elaborate  the line "the result still retract to a point"?

Comment: You have $h_t(x)=tx, x\in X, t\in [0,1]$ is such a retraction.

Comment: Elegant, simple, thank you. I'm a bit embarrassed for not seeing that.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the set of points that have a neighborhood homeomomorphic to the upper half plane.

This is is a homeomorphism invariant, right? (It requires proof.)

What is it in the first case? The second? (The computation requires proof, of course.)

Comment: Don't you mean 'neighborhood homeomorphic to an open subset of the upper half plane'?

Comment: @udit.m  I don't think it matters since $B_\epsilon(0) \cap H \cong H$ - where $H$ is the upper half plane, $B_\epsilon(0)$ is an open ball of radius $\epsilon$ around 0, and $\cong$ means homeomorphism.

Comment: Yes, you're right.